# Issue with type using Ramda expression

Tags: typescript, types, ramda.js

I am trying to construct type assertion using Ramda. The assertion should check that it is a number and not a null. As a paramter any type should fit.I have tried the following option, but in this case the parameter is typed as number.

```
number: R.both(R.is(Number), R.complement(R.equals(NaN)))
```

[image]

Comment: A type that is a number and not null is just a number?

Comment: Yes. I want to check from code different values. And this simple method should return if it is a number, which is not NaN. But i want to do it using Ramda. But not to write in code like `is.number(value as number)`